# How to install an APK from Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a `BroadcastReceiver`, I download an apk from the server, when I catch action `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` I install the apk using

```
activity.startActivityForResult(my_intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Now I want to move this logic in a `Service` and also install the apk, but inside the service I don't have a Activity, I can to cast context to Activity obtained from getapplicationcontext(), but I catch the error that context can't be casted to com.android.Activity

How I can to run installation of apk from this Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-hostile approach is to call `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`. This is user-hostile as it automatically starts up an installer UI, and your service has no idea what the user is doing in the foreground. Interrupting the user will not make the user very happy.

A related user-hostile approach is to start your own activity from the service, where your own activity then calls `startActivityForResult()`. You could use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` so your own activity has no UI, but, again, you will be starting the installer activity, which will interrupt the user.

The user-friendly approach is to raise a `Notification` when the download is complete. Either put the `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` `Intent` in the `Notification` itself, or have the notification start your activity, which in turn calls `startActivityForResult()`. This allows the user to install the app when the *user* wants to, which may or may not be right now.

Comment: Good answer, best is to not start an activity the user is not expecting.

Comment: I want to start installation process immediate after download complete without show any notifications, I can to kill my app but service must catch this action when is complete download and run install of apk

Comment: @Alex: "I want to start installation process immediate after download complete without show any notifications" -- what you want is immaterial. What your **users** want is important. A user has to be involved in installing or upgrading the app, as there will be 1+ screens that the user has to navigate through to accept the APK. You are welcome to use one of the user-hostile approaches that I outline in my answer, but your users may not appreciate it, and users are *very* creative about how they express their displeasure.